# Why do people lose their appetite while having a fever?

Tags: digestion, body-temperature, fever, loss-of-appetite, hunger-hungry

Fevers raise the body's temperature, therefore requiring more energy.

Why, then, is a loss of appetite a characteristic of fevers if food would provide the essential extra energy used to raise the body's temperature?